# Angular 2 : Error Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.ts(2339)

Tags: json, angular, error-handling, syntax-error

I try to program a function but somehow the error pops up:
when I want to .map (res => res.json());
what did I do wrong here? I use the newest Angular Version.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Contact} from './contact';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //retrieving ContactService
  getContacts()
  {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/contacts')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
  //add contact method
  addContact(newContact) {
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/contact', newContact, {headers:headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  //delete methods
deleteContact(id)
{
  return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/contact'+ id)
  .map(res => res.json());
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're coming from an older version of RxJS and HttpClient. In the latest versions you need the following adjustments.

1. If you're using newer versions of RxJS, the `map` should be applied using `pipe`.

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';    // <-- deprecated

import { map } from 'rxjs';        // <-- new

return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/contact'+ id).pipe(
  map(res => res.json())
);
```

2. In the newer versions of Angular, the `res.json()` isn't required. The fetched data is already a JS object if it was one. So you can just say

```js
return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/contact'+ id);
```